# How to partition the space allocated to Root directory

Tags: 14.04

My Hard disk is of 500 GB and I did Ubuntu installation on my machine by erasing every thing. Now I see 4Gb space has been allocated to swap space( My machine RAM size is 4GB) and the rest of the space allocated to ROOT directory by default.

Could you please any one help me if i could partition this root space like the way we have in windows operating system?

I am keeping my personal data in home directory and suspecting this would be gone if i do re-installation in future.

Comment: I believe the user directory and root directory are all on the same drive c: partition in windows. This is no different that what you have now.

Comment: " like the way we have in windows operating system?" and what would that be? >:-D "I am keeping my personal data in home directory and suspecting this would be gone if i do re-installation in future." ONLY if you tell the system to do that. Ubuntu will happily keep your /home/ when re-installing... just got to tell the system to do that... Linux is NOT Windows. We do things with multi-user in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Always do a backup first, however, when you do a reinstall in the future, follow the following instructions to keep the data in your home directory.

When you get to the part of the installation that asks if you would like to install Ubuntu **along side** your current operating system, choose **something else**.

Then right click on the Ubuntu partition, select the mount point "**/**"and **DO NOT PLACE A TICK IN THE BOX TO FORMAT THE PARTITION**. Choose the format type as ext4 (or whatever is currently in place) and continue with the installation. Again, make sure there is **no tick** in the box to format the partition . . . do not format the partition.

If you **do not** format the partition, the home directory will not be overwritten and you will keep your data.

Comment: Thank you much for taking time and writing your suggestions.